# Gathering jmeter slave metrics in influxdb

Tags: configuration, jmeter, distributed, influxdb

As a project we have setup a jmeter cluster with  a master and 5 salve nodes.
We also configured influxDb for storing the metrics and grafana for visualization.

we have connection from jmeter to influxdb and are able to visualize the data.

The influxdb confguration is done on the master and if we run standalone on master, we are able to see the live data with all the detailed visualization in Grafana.

Issue : When we run the test in distributed mode, we see the result on grafana, but it looks all broken, looks all the data is not getting into influxdb.

1. How to get all the details of the slave execution to influxdb?
2. Are there any specific configuration to get all the details from jmeter to influxdb.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your slave instances are able to connect to InfluxDB and store the metrics there, i.e. verify connectivity to InfluxDB TCP or HTTP port using [telnet](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026) client or equivalent, it might be the case the connections are blocked by the [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))
2. Check `jmeter-server.log` file on slave machines for any suspicious entries. You might want to [increase JMeter logs verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for the [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.influxdb" level="debug"/>
   ```

   in case of success you should see the lines like:

   > HttpMetricsSender: Success, number of metrics written: x
   >
   > ...
   >
   > InfluxdbBackendListenerClient: Sending last metrics
3. If you want to see separate results for Samplers originating from different slaves consider adding [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function to Samplers labels

Comment: Thank Dmitri. When you run a jmeter-server on the slave. The slave collects all the details and sends it back to master and master is connected to influxdb. where can i cofingure the slave to talk to influxdb.